# How to split the header line on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the very simple website header - title on the left side, menu items on the right. The problem is that it looks bad on the mobile devices with smaller screen resolution.

I'd like to not show menu items on the right when there's nothing on the left. Any ideas how can it be implemented in the simplest way? I experimented a little bit with the styles but didn't find anything that worked well.

Standard view (on PC):

[image]

Current mobile view:

[image]

Simplified code (I'm actually using the SASS, not CSS style embedded inside the `head`):

```
<html>
  <head>
      <style>
      .header {
          position: relative;
          min-height: 50px;
      }

      .title {
          font-size: 3em;
          font-weight: 300;
          line-height: 50px;
          letter-spacing: -1px;
          margin-bottom: 0;
          float: left;
      }      

      .navigation {
        line-height: 50px;
        float: right;
      }     
      </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div>
      <a class="title" href="/">Webpage Title</a>
      <nav class="navigation">
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Project</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, what you want to archive. Could you explain a little further, how you want it to look on mobile?

Comment: Are you already familiar with `@media` queries? These will allow you to add conditional css based on any number of a very large set of queries. Conventionally `@media` queries are used to customise user-interfaces at different break-points, so that regardless of whether the user is using a handheld touchscreen or a very large desktop monitor, the UI is optimised for the screen on which it's displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [@media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) to your CSS like this:

```css
.header {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.title {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 50px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    float: left;
}      

.navigation {
  line-height: 50px;
  float: right;
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .title { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
   <div>
     <a class="title" href="/">Webpage Title</a>
     <nav class="navigation">
         <a href="#">About</a>
         <a href="#">Project</a>
         <a href="#">Contact</a>
     </nav>
   </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: Thanks! I set `min-width: 700px` for both `float: left` and `float:right` and the result is satisfactory.